# why isn't file.writelines(str) working in a while loop

Tags: python, debugging

When I create todo-item, I want to add input content to my file. Why can’t I achieve the expected effect when I add a string in `file.writeline()`?

I want to use `file.writeline()` to write the content entered by the user into a file.

```
while True:
   user_action = input('Type add, show, edit, complete or exit: ')
   user_action = user_action.strip()

   match user_action:
       case 'add':
           todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n"
           todos.append((todo))
           file = open("todos.txt", "w")
           file.writelines(todo)
```

Comment: Personally I would not add to the file within the loop. Open once and write all data once.

Answer (score 1):

`writelines` takes a list, not a string. For what you are trying to do I'd recommend `write`, which does take a string. If you do this you'd also need to open the file in append mode, which means you pass `"a"` and not `"w"`. The whole code would look like this:

```py
todos = []

while True: 
    user_action = input('Type add, show, edit, complete or exit: ') 
    user_action = user_action.strip()

    match user_action:
        case 'add': 
            todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n" 
            todos.append((todo))
            with open("todos.txt", "a") as file:
                file.write(todo)
```

Comment: `with open("todos.txt", "a") as file:` - why would you do this within the loop?

Comment: Partly to retain as much of OP's code as possible. Also because it looks like OP wants to have operations to add, view, and edit the list; so the user might need to see the entire file, including things added before the program began running. This could be done with a list, but it might make more sense as well as give OP more practice to open and close it within the loop. Doing it all at the end would work too of course! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** You were opening file in `'w'(write)` mode because of which, everytime you attempt to write into the file, the previous content gets overwritten.
**Solution:** Open file using `'a'(append)` mode

**Improvement:** Do not open a file inside a loop (this leads to unwanted processing), better to open it (just once) after collecting all todos.

**Assumption:** I hope you're using "default case" at the end of the match statement (for eg: `case _`)

> Here is the final code:

```
todos = []

while True:
    user_action = input('Type add, show, edit, complete or exit: ')
    user_action = user_action.strip()
    match user_action:
        case 'add':
           todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n"
           todos.append((todo))
           
        case _: break

with open("todos.txt", "a") as file:
    file.writelines(todos)
```